# What's a good way to preserve my wood fence in Arizona sun while also letting it age?

Tags: wood, fence

I just had a new wood privacy fence installed and want to make sure I maintain it well. It's made of 1x6 spruce boards cut in 6ft lengths. The boards are set at an angle (letting some light into the courtyard) and it runs north/south. The trick, I think, is that I'd like the wood to age in terms of color while avoiding excessive warp and rot.

This is in Phoenix, so fairly dry but intense sun exposure. The landscape surrounding it will be desert plants with either 1/4"-minus aggregate or wood mulch ground cover.

In terms of products, most seem to be focused on total UV protection, termite prevention, waterproofing, etc. I assume most have a combination of oils and other chemicals or varnishes. Would a generic oil treatment (linseed?) be better? If not, is there a combination of product ingredients I should look for?

[image: front_view][image: rear_view][image: side_view]

Answer (score 1):

Go visit a nearby ghost town.

Observe.

Question the need to apply "preservative" for the rest of your life. Or beyond.

You're in a dry climate, rot is slow to occur.

Or linseed oil (traditionally, raw for outside wood, boiled for inside.) Just dipping the ends (or letting them soak for a while while standing up) will address the area most prone to any issues in the illustrated design.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options, in my experience:

- Apply a gray stain/sealer. There are plenty out there designed specifically to look like aged barnwood.
- Use a chemical aging solution, and then seal. Lime sulfur comes to mind, but there may be others with less objectionable odor. Once that ages for a few weeks, wash the fence to remove residue, then seal once it's completely dry.

Or, as Ecnerwal astutely suggests, just let it be. Suspended fir in a dry climate lasts for decades, and a little character is part of the charm of aged wood.

Answer (score -1):

Try this...[Olympic Water Guard](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Olympic-WaterGuard-1-gal-Clear-Multi-Surface-Exterior-Wood-Sealer-55548XIA-01/315988854?source=shoppingads&locale=en-US&&mtc=SHOPPING-RM-RMP-GGL-D24-024_011_EXT_STAIN_WS-NA-OLYMPIC-NA-SMART-NA-NA-MK493963300-9016832838-NBR-673-CON-NA-FY22_673&cm_mmc=SHOPPING-RM-RMP-GGL-D24-024_011_EXT_STAIN_WS-NA-OLYMPIC-NA-SMART-NA-NA-MK493963300-9016832838-NBR-673-CON-NA-FY22_673-71700000085764770-58700007293127231-92700074638383300&gclid=Cj0KCQiA_bieBhDSARIsADU4zLcwYbDDc_YK-FtlDWmtZucBvZ7Ro2tKHNc-szmVNZN9eJWdx-SyyJgaAoHIEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds)  It seals wood but lets it weater to a gray naturally.

Comment: Thanks! I saw this at HD but I guess I missed the part about it allowing the wood to natural gray.

Comment: This is, explicitly, a product recommendation, which is, explicitly off-topic and why this question got closed. What makes this brand better than others? What if it's no longer available? What if it's not available in some other reader's part of the world? That's why we don't do product recommendations...

Comment: @FreeMan Shopping _questions_ are off-topic but I don't think shopping _answers_ are.

Comment: For clarity, I did not recommend the product. I only brought it to the op's attention since it provided all the properties he was looking for.